# Rails Devise allows 1 person to register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, singleton, registration

I am having a Rails app for personal use and it uses Devise for authentication. I want there is only one user for my app. In other words, how do I disable registration in Devise after there is already 1 user registered ?

I am thinking about creating a custom method in controller. But is there any good way to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to remove the `:registerable` option in the model. Then create your single account in your `seed.rb` and then just seed your app. No need to complicate things just for your own use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, supposed I don't want to put into seeds.rb because it contains password, how should I do? I am thinking of overriding devise controller. Do you have any suggestion on that approach ?

Comment: Well, you could always change the password after you seed it. Devise has all those goodies built in. Or you can always seed it manually, meaning, `rails console` then create the user model directly in there.